# how can i embed a YouTube-Video in my Swift-App without calling the YouTube-Url

Tags: image, cocoa, video, youtube, path

I´m writing an app to generate birthday-mails in Swift.

Now I want to embed Youtube-Videos as attachments, i.e. "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY40WVWlk2k". But I don´t want to see any playlist (don´t know the right word, I mean the red-borded area in this screenshot).

[image]

I´ve read, that there is a way to do this without calling the YouTube-Url. I just know, that I have to use the **video-path** of the video.

So I need to know, how to **get** this path with my **Mac** and how to **use this** in my app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to embed web view and give it the embed URL. This is a simple tutorial which gives the answer to your problem.

[Tutorial](https://youtu.be/Rg6GLVUnnpM)

Comment: hey, that´s what i searched! THX :-)

Comment: great! can you pls mark the answer as correct answer.